# Get Stream from Properties.Resources in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, csv, stream, resources, streamreader

I have seen lots of posts outthere regarding this and could not get any to work.  I added a file to Resources folder of my project (right click on project->Properties->Resources, then select File, Add File).

I tried setting Build Action to both Resources and Embedded Resources.

I need to read that file using StreamReader.

I have tried following but both return NULL for myStream regardless whether I set Build Action to Resources or Embedded Resource:

```
    // IF I ADD FILE AS SUGGESTED BELOW IN UPDATE, THIS WILL WORK; OTHERWISE, I GET NULL   
    Stream myStream = Assembly
      .GetExecutingAssembly()
      .GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.General.Tests.mytestfile.csv"); //returns NULL
    using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(myStream), true)
    {
       ... 
    }
```

I have also tried this but it also returns NULL

```
Stream myStream = Assembly
  .GetExecutingAssembly()
  .GetManifestResourceStream(Properties.Resources.mytestfile); //returns NULL
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(myStream), true)
{
   ...
}
```

If I go to quick watch and type this Properties.Resources.mytestfile, I do get string representation of my file back.

**UPDATE**, INSTEAD OF ADDING THE FILE BY RIGHT CLICKING ON PROJECT->PROPERTIES->RESOURCES (THIS WAY, IT WILL NOT WORK), ADD IT BY RIGHT CLICKING ON PROJECT->ADD->EXISTING ITEM, THEN SET BUILD ACTION=EMBEDDED RESOURCE, IT WILL WORK. (Thanks to Aedvald Tseh for his detailed answer that helped me figure this)

Comment: It is not a stream, it is embedded as a string.  So use new StringReader(Properties.Resources.mytestfile)

Comment: That is not working.  I tried setting mytestfile as BuildAction=Resource and Build Action = Embedded Resource, none work.  App crashes, see no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your csv-file as embedded resource to the studio project. 
[image: csv file as embedded resource]

Prefix the name of your file with default namespace of your visual studio project. Thus "mytestfile.csv" is turned into "ConsoleApp1.mytestfile.csv".
Then you can read the content like so:

```
System.IO.Stream myStream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("ConsoleApp1.mytestfile.csv");
```

Comment: Tried that already.  The stream returned is null as per above description.  I tried setting Build Action to both Embedded Resource and Resource, either one returns null

Comment: You are correct, it works if you add the csv file to the project as you described.  If you add it the way I described, it will not work which is strange.  Much appreciated Aedvald